# How do I retreive a file from FILESTREAM?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, filestream, ole-automation

I have installed SQL Server Express on my machine and enabled and configured FILESTREAM to store and retrieve pdf's from SQL Server. I have successfully uploaded files to my table as BLOB's, but I am having difficulty retrieving them. My approach is to use a temporary directory to create the files in so I can open them. I have the following code:

I have configured ole automation

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

I have the following record in my table BusinessFiles:

```
    FileID          415578C7-B058-49A5-A1E4-5A4E7218EA19
    InvoiceID   99999
    FileName    file1
    FileType    pdf
    ImageFile   0x255044462D312…
```

This next piece of code apparently will create the file from the filestream.

```
DECLARE 
@FILE VARBINARY(MAX)
,@FILEPATH VARCHAR(MAX)
,@ObjectToken INT
,@FileType VARCHAR(MAX)
,@FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX)

Set @FILENAME = (SELECT [FileName] FROM BusinessFiles where FileID = '415578C7-B058-49A5-A1E4-5A4E7218EA19')
Set @FileType = (SELECT FileType FROM BusinessFiles where FileID = '415578C7-B058-49A5-A1E4-5A4E7218EA19')
SELECT @FILE = ImageFile FROM BusinessFiles where FileID = '415578C7-B058-49A5-A1E4-5A4E7218EA19'
Set @FILEPATH = CONCAT('C:\Users\user\Desktop\', @FILENAME,'.',@FileType)

EXEC sp_OACREATE 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @FILE
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FILEPATH, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken 
Go
```

This code runs and I get the Commands Completed successfully message. However there is nothing in my folder C:\Users\user\Desktop. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks;

I've verified the file path is correct and all the set's are good.

Comment: You're not checking the return values of the functions you execute though.

Comment: How do I check the return value of the sp's? a select?

Comment: E.g. `DECLARE @hr INT; DECLARE @object_token INT; EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @object_token OUTPUT; 
IF @hr<>0 PRINT 'fail';`. The OLE functions return a HRESULT value. If it isn't 0, your function failed.

Comment: ok this SavetoFile function failed... but the path is correct... When I select the filepath generated it's all spelled correctly and I can navigate to it in my PC...

Comment: Your database engine needs to be able to access the folder of course, meaning it can only access folders on the database server itself plus it has to have permissions to do file actions there.

Comment: What permissions should I be sure to have 'on' so that I can make sure that's not the cause of the error. I.e what sp_configure script to turn on? I should mention that I'm using localDB with SQl express so everything is on my machine - no remote server or anything

Comment: Have you tried in another directory?

Comment: I have tried other folders in C: yielding the failed result. I don't have any other mapped drives.

Comment: Crazy. I created a folder called temp in C: root. In SQL, I changed the directory to C:\Temp and it worked. I guess SQL doesn't want to use users folder for anything FILESTREAM related

Comment: It's a question of permissions of the account with which SQL Server engine does these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the permissions of SQL Server will fix the SaveToFile Issue. In my case, I changed the SavetoFile Directory to C:\temp.